# Minimum Spanning Tree of Max Cost Complexity Class Problem

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, space-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree, np

**"Decide whether a given undirected graph G=(V,E) with positive edge costs has a minimum spanning tree of cost at most K".**
Is this a problem of **P, NP, CoNP, RP or BPP?**

I am fair sure that it is in NP, as there is a way to 'guess' and verify that guess in polynomial time.
But I am thinking that it is in P as well, as well use the Prim Algorithm within polynomial time as well. 
If it is in both P & NP. Is it fair to say that it is in CoNP, RP & BPP as well? As P is a subset of CoNP, whereas RP is a subset of NP, & RP is also a subset of BPP. Is it fair to say that the problem above is in all of the 5 complexity classes - P, NP, CoNP, RP or BPP?
 I am unsure if I misunderstood any of the concepts here. But please let me know if what I understand is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is exactly right. You can answer this question in polynomial time by using Prim's algorithm to find a minimum spanning tree for *G*, and then comparing the cost of that tree to *K*. (By the definition of "minimum spanning tree", all minimum spanning trees for a given graph have the same cost, so you only need to check one of them.) Therefore, the problem is in P; and since P is a subset of each of NP, co-NP, RP and BPP, that means that the problem is in each of those complexity classes as well.